# How can I use JavaScript to parse html code that includes php tags?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I had tried using the [tautologistics node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser), which handles javascript fine, but it chokes on php tags.  I only need to parse the html and the php tags.  Not within the php tags themselves--I don't need a php AST or anything.  Is there an existing library that can do this?

Here are some examples:

```
<span id="<?="1"?>" <?php print \'class="2"\'?>><?php print "3"?></span>

<p><?php print "?>";?></p>
```

Edit:  Please stop with all the "php will be executed before javascript" answers.  That doesn't apply here.  I'm writing an IDE that runs in the browser where users can type html and php code.  I then need to then parse what is typed.

Comment: Are you doing parsing on client side or on server side? On client you can't do that (because PHP is execute before JS).

Comment: Not using javascript, as php will be executed before javascript.

Comment: Client-side, and yes I can do that.  I'm writing an html editor with a wysiwyg mode, and the html may have php code in it.  I need to properly parse that into comments so it interferes as little as possible with the html.  I doubt I can handle every case but I can get the simple ones.

Comment: Hm, if it's a client side  work, the PHP would be executed before JS, unless you're getting PHP from PHP via file_get_contents or something like that. You can parse content of <?(php)  ?> tags (if you get them from AJAX or from other way) and then parse it your self.

Comment: Correct, the php code is unexecuted php code when JavaScript has it.  I'm asking this because I don't want to have to write a parser myself.  node-htmlparser is already a thousand lines and doesn't handle embedded php tags.

Comment: Why are there two votes to close this question?  Can someone help me understand how to better follow proper StackOverflow etiquette?

Comment: The close votes are pretty self-explanatory: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Sorry, but it's true, the only question of this thread asks for a library.

Comment: Right, I'm asking for a library.  Where is the appropriate place to ask such a question?  programmers.stackexchange ?

Comment: It looks like programmers.stackexchange isn't the best place either.  I see questions asking for library recommendations also being flagged there:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271584/what-cms-to-use-for-mean-js